# Cannot boot after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, upgrade

The system told me there was a new version for ubuntu and I upgraded it. After upgrading, it showed some error message saying the system is unstable. I didn't pay attention to that and restarted it. It turned out that I cannot boot and it even told me there is no Ubuntu system. I tried the recovery mode using old kernel. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me? I really don't want to reinstall everything again. Speaking of reinstalling, I tried to reinstall using usb, it cannot detect any ubuntu system.

Comment: Can you try boot repair disk, since it could solve the issue if is it with booting the os  ?

Comment: From the recovery mode? I tried that, but it didn't work, and lead me to a safe mode.

Comment: For boot related problems there is a specifically dedicated iso that is aka Boot Repair Disc which can be used to repair most of the boot problems. For more check this link out. http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/

Comment: @FakabbirAmin Thanks. I tried this but it didn't work. I have to reinstall the system I guess.

Comment: I guess, if reinstalling is the last option, you can reinstall it at other partition by using gpart at installation or other effective ways that could help to retain the old data....Can you exactly tell me what happens when you boot your pc ?

Comment: @FakabbirAmin, I have reinstalled the system. It even didn't detect the installed system when reinstalling it. Thanks anyway!